# Querying Distant Relationships

Tags: laravel, foreach, eloquent

I have three tables: `users`, `accounts` and `hotels.` Users and Accounts are connected with `belongstoMany` relation and Accounts and Hotels are connected the same way. Each User has Accounts and those Accounts have Hotels.

When I have `Auth::user(),` how I can return all hotels?

```php
$accounts = Auth::user()->accounts()->get();
```

With the above statement, I can get all Accounts. How can I return all Hotels?

WHAT I TRIED?

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $accounts = Auth::user()->accounts()->get();
        $hotels = collect();
        foreach ($accounts as $key => $a) {

            $h = $a->hotels();
            $hotels = $hotels->toBase()->merge($h);

                }
            dd($hotels);
        return view('hotels.index',compact('hotels'));

    }
```

but this code dont return me hotels collection which I can use in blade view files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Case 1

In the case you have a relationship as shown in the diagram below

[image: user accounts hotels relationship]

What you are looking for is the `hasManyThrough` relationship.

From the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

> The "has-many-through" relationship provides a convenient shortcut for accessing distant relations via an intermediate relation

In your case, on your User model, you can define the relationship

```php
public function hotels()
{
  return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Hotel', 'App\Account');
}
```

To then get your collection of hotels you can simply use

```php
$hotels = Auth::user()->hotels;
```

You can also provide extra arguments to the `hasManyThrough` function to define the keys that are used on each table, great examples of this are given in the documentation linked above!

## Case 2

If, instead, you have a relation as shown in the following diagram

[image: distant many-to-many relation]

It is a little more tricky (or, at least, less clean). The best solution I can think of, that uses the fewest queries is to use `with`.

```php
$accounts = Auth::user()->accounts()->with('hotels')->get();
```

Will give you a collection of accounts, each with a `hotels` child. Now, all we have to do is get the hotels as a standalone collection, this is simple with some neat collection functions provided by Laravel.

```php
$hotels = $accounts->flatMap(function($account) {
  return $account->hotels;
})->unique(function ($hotel) {
  return $hotel->id;
});
```

This will do the job of creating a collection of hotels. In my opinion, ***it would be cleaner and more efficient*** to simply make a new relationship as shown below.

[image: a simpler many-to-many relationship]

And then to perform queries, using basic Eloquent methods.

Comment: I tried but I got error: ""SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Accounts.user_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `Hotels`.*, `Accounts`.`user_id` from `Hotels` inner join ▶""

Comment: users and accounts are stored in account_user table and hotels and accounts connection are stored into hotel_account table ...

Comment: so hasManyThrough doesnt work in my case and I after I got accounts I need to make foreach loop and look for hotels and after that group by ID ? right ?

Comment: @AleksPer , Yes, I see. I misunderstood the relationships. I will have to think about the best way to do it for your setup and post an update. In general, you want to minimise the number of queries so you certainly don't want query in a for loop as this could have massive consequences on your response time!

Comment: Yes, I dont want foreach loop and also relations between users and accounts are many-to-many also the is between accounts and hotels. Thanks for helping me

Comment: How this will looks like with foreach loop? There is no other way just foreach loop...

Comment: I have updated my above answer, I think it should now provide a solution to the relationship situation you provide!

Comment: Thanks very much! The case 2 help me a lot. I will think to create hotel_user table but in that case every time I update account_user I need to update hotel_user too ...